# IntentService vs AsyncTask for Login Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

I want to make a login activity in my app that uses a web service. What is the best practice to make the request?

Should I use an IntentService or should I use the AsynkTask class and override its methods?

Comment: what kind of webservice it is ?

Comment: Use `AsncTask` for small time Web-Service.

Comment: @jiteshmohite is a Java SOAP ws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `AsyncTask` will help to make your code much more simpler in your case.
In this case you will use just one class into another. In this case you transfer the data in the most easiest way.

In the second case - intentservice - you have to write/read/collect/extract your data, time lags and so on.

**EDIT**
1. You can cancel request before rotation
2. You can check if your request is in progress and do not launch it again.
3. You can disable rotation in the login screen.

Comment: @MateutAlin even if you rotate screen intent service also call again. You have to check whether current data is right with you. before requesting.

Answer (score 3):

If you use an `IntentService` you will have to implement a Binder to communicate with the UI whereas an `AsyncTask` provides callback for updating the UI.

However, an `AsyncTask` has a drawback that it is started every time the calling activity is started. So, to handle this issue you can use an `AsyncTaskLoader` which provides an `AsyncTask` for your background work and handles its state to avoid starting it again through configuration changes.

Android developer tutorial has a pretty good example of how to use an `AsyncTaskLoader`. You can find it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should use Aysnc task because  IntentService is run in background so you have to update UI after network call response.

So async task is better for your case.

IntentService we use for long background running task which will terminate it self after work done.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask just runs the action async in the class.

IntentService runs a new service and does the action you want.

It would be much easier to use AsyncTask, because as you can use it inside your activity, you can run an intent from it to the target activity(registrer, the user area, etc).

If you use a IntentService, you would have to create binders, collect data, monitor it and more. IntentService, for this purpose, would be much more work than it is worth.